# Vueresource wait for the previous http request to complete and then perform the next request

Tags: vuejs2, vue-resource

Am trying to load a large dataset and break it down by fetching data in small intervals

So that is

Suppose i have 1000 records and i would like to get data in steps of 10 but only request the next 10 when the current request is complete

so currently this is what am doing but its making multiple http requests and i cant know when one is complete or not

```
  processData(){
    this.fetchedtrucks = 0;
    this.dataLoadingCmplete = false;
    this.exportstart = true;
    this.ttatdatatrucks = [];
    let i = 0;
    do {
        const page = (i == 0) ? 0 : (i / (this.paginatorval));
        //send http request

          this.$http.get("v1/data-trucks",
                {
                    from: this.duration_from,
                    to: this.duration_to,
                    page: page,
                    pagination: this.paginatorval,
                    filters: this.filters,
                    only_completed: this.only_completed,
                    non_reg: this.non_reg
                }
            ).then(
                res => {
                    this.ttatdatatrucks = this.ttatdatatrucks.concat(this.getTransformedData(res.ttatdata));
                    this.fetchedtrucks += this.paginatorval;
                    if (this.fetchedtrucks >= this.totalRecords) {
                        this.dataLOadingCompleted();
                    }


                }, err => {
                    this.fetchedtrucks += this.paginatorval;
                    this.errorloadingdata = true;
                }
            )

        i += this.paginatorval;

    } while (i < this.totalRecords);
```

The above works but not very neat as when i check on the browser dev tools i can see over 100 http requests issued what am looking forward to do is to issue the next http request only when the current request is completed

How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because your do..while loop is kicking off all of the http requests at once. It is not concerned with your promise as it is defined externally to that.

Without refactoring a lot of your code, the easiest way to handle this issue would be to use the JavaScript async / await key word. I'll demonstrate that solution, but if you are unable to use these operators then I'll outline how to refactor your code to get what you want.

First the easy way:
you need to make processData asynchronous so you can put an await operator inside of it. You do that by adding the async key word in the processData declaration - like so:

```
async processData() {...
```

next you will need to remove the .then wrapper and use the await operator instead. Your code inside of the do..while will look like this:

```
     try {
            const res = await this.$http.get("v1/data-trucks",
                {
                    from: this.duration_from,
                    to: this.duration_to,
                    page: page,
                    pagination: this.paginatorval,
                    filters: this.filters,
                    only_completed: this.only_completed,
                    non_reg: this.non_reg
                }
            )
            this.ttatdatatrucks = 
            this.ttatdatatrucks.concat(this.getTransformedData(res.ttatdata));
            this.fetchedtrucks += this.paginatorval;
            if (this.fetchedtrucks >= this.totalRecords) {
                this.dataLOadingCompleted();                    
     } catch (err) {
             this.fetchedtrucks += this.paginatorval;
             this.errorloadingdata = true;
     }
```

This code will make your do while loop take a long time to run, but it will meet your requirement of waiting for each http request to complete for doing the next one.

Now if the await operator is unavailable then you'll need to do away with the do...while loop. I don't think you could easily make that work. I'll outline what you'll need to do instead.

1) remove the do...while loop

2) add your i variable and any other appropriate variables as parameters to your processData loop

3) call processData() recursively from the .then block of your http request

4) make sure to add appropriate logic to your function to exit recursion

it would look a little bit like this:

```
processData(i, complete) {
 if (i >= complete) return;
 this.$http.get()...
 .then(res => {
    //do processing and stuff
    i++
    processData(i, complete)
})
```

this isn't true recursion, I guess - this is just a do...while disguised as recursion, but it will achieve the result you're after which is synchronous http requests